# Accessing an Array inside A Parsed JSON Response in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I have the following parsed JSON response from an API

```
emp = 
{
  "response": [
    {
      "image_fingerprint": null,
      "image_source_fingerprint": null,
      "last_name": "LastName",
      "location": "G564",
      "notes": "A great worker",
      "online_seating": {
        "seat_urls": []
      },
      "photo": "/images/employee.jpg",
      "seating": {
        "seated": "not seated",
        "seat_urls": [
                "/api/1/seats/33444",
                "/api/1/seats/55323",
                "/api/1/seats/62229"
            ]
      },
      "show_in_vd": true,
      "start_date": "2014-01-02",
    },

    {
      "image_fingerprint": null,
      "image_source_fingerprint": null,
      "last_name": "LastName",
      "location": "G564",
      "notes": "A great worker",
      "online_seating": {
        "seat_urls": []
      },
      "photo": "/images/employee.jpg",
      "seating": {
        "seated": "not seated",
        "seat_urls": [
                "/api/1/seats/56580",
                "/api/1/seats/69856",
                "/api/1/seats/50003"
            ]
      },
      "show_in_vd": true,
      "start_date": "2014-01-02",
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to compare the array seat_urls that is inside that response to the following array

```
shiftA = ["/api/1/seats/50003","/api/1/seats/62229", "/api/1/seats/556565"]
```

And return all the data from emp if any of the URLs in shiftA matches the URLs in emp.seat_urls

I have tried

```
var shiftAEmp =  emp.seating.seat_urls.filter(value => shiftA.includes(value))
```

and many others but I keep getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'seat_urls' of undefined**

I tried other filter approaches with no luck it just seam I can't access the seat_urls inside the JSON file emp **(sometimes seats_urls cab=n be empty by the way)**

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you are missing response. `emp.response` it will work for you.

Comment: @sibabratswain I tried adding .response same issue

Comment: Please check this `https://codepen.io/sibabrat_swain/pen/RwrWMeJ` check your console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the updated `emp` object below with running code:

```js
var emp = {
  "response": [{
      "image_fingerprint": null,
      "image_source_fingerprint": null,
      "last_name": "LastName",
      "location": "G564",
      "notes": "A great worker",
      "online_seating": {
        "seat_urls": []
      },
      "photo": "/images/employee.jpg",
      "seating": {
        "seated": "not seated",
        "seat_urls": [
          "/api/1/seats/33444",
          "/api/1/seats/55323",
          "/api/1/seats/62229"
        ]
      },
      "show_in_vd": true,
      "start_date": "2014-01-02",
    },
    {
      "image_fingerprint": null,
      "image_source_fingerprint": null,
      "last_name": "LastName",
      "location": "G564",
      "notes": "A great worker",
      "online_seating": {
        "seat_urls": []
      },
      "photo": "/images/employee.jpg",
      "seating": {
        "seated": "not seated",
        "seat_urls": [
          "/api/1/seats/56580",
          "/api/1/seats/69856",
          "/api/1/seats/50003"
        ]
      },
      "show_in_vd": true,
      "start_date": "2014-01-02",
    }
  ]
};

var shiftA = ["/api/1/seats/50003","/api/1/seats/62229", "/api/1/seats/556565"];
var rd = emp.response.filter(r => r.seating.seat_urls.some(u => shiftA.includes(u)));

console.log(rd);
```

Comment: the final response should be all of emp.response that matches the seat_urls this is only returning matched seats_url

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things `emp` is an object that contains an array. You'd need to do something like...

```
emp.Response[0].seating.....
```

Or alternatively map the responses

```
emp.Response.map(myEmp=>{emp.Response[0].seating....})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var shiftAEmp = emp.response.filter(r => {
return r.seating.seat_urls.some(u => shiftA.includes(u));
)
```

For `some` method, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

Comment: this answer needs explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think

`var shiftAEmp =  emp.seating.seat_urls.filter(value => shiftA.includes(value))`

is wrong. It should be

`emp.Response[0].seating..`

`emp.Response[1].seating..`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

You are comparing the `emp.seating.seat_urls` directly, whereas they are arrays, you have to execute it with every item in the array!
Try below code!

Get the seat_curls in a variable to simplify the code, and if it works then replace it after!

And bring the whole thing in a function to have proper control over the work!

```
let shiftA = ["/api/1/seats/50003","/api/1/seats/62229", "/api/1/seats/556565"];
let seatUrls = emp.seating.seat_urls;

function compareSeating(shift1, shiftResponse){
  let shiftAEmp = [];
  shift1.forEach((itemsOfShiftA) => shiftResponse.forEach(itemsOfShiftResponse) => {
     if (itemsOfShiftA === itemsOfShiftResponse) {
        shiftAEmp.push(itemsOfShiftA)
     }
  }
));
return shiftAEmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var shiftAEmp =  emp.response[0].seating.seat_urls.filter(value => shiftA.includes(value))
//for the first element since its an array
//OR
//for all
var shiftAEmp = emp.response.map(a=>{
  return a.seating.seat_urls.filter(value => shiftA.includes(value))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you the solution with each loop. Please follow this.

```
resultantArray = [];
emp.response.forEach((arr) => {
    if(arr.online_seating.seat_url) {
      resultantArray.push(...arr.online_seating.seat_url)
    }
    if(arr.seating.seat_urls) {
      resultantArray.push(...arr.seating.seat_urls)
    }
});


const intersection = resultantArray.filter(x => shiftA.includes(x));
console.log(intersection);
```